# why can't i access the private function from within the class?

Tags: ruby, oop, private

The following code prints `NoMethodError`. I don't understand the reason . Though the method i am calling is private but i am calling it from within the class.Can't a class var  access it's private variable/function ?. I could do this in Java.

```
class Tester
 private
   def func_pri
     puts("From a private function")
   end

 protected 
  def func_prot
    puts("From a protected function")
  end

 public
  def func_pub
     puts("From a public function")
  end

 public
  def caller(object)
    object.func_pub
    object.func_pri # This statement causes error
    object.func_prot
  end
 end

 o = Tester.new
 o.caller(o)
```

Comment: When you use object as a parameter, you are calling this method from outside the scope. Use send, or in caller method, do self.fun_pri

Comment: What language is this (ohhh, it was ruby) ? And why do you pass <object> to <caller> function ? <caller> thinks it calls <func_pri> of some other <object> which it can not !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot call private methods on an object, not even on `self`. Remove the `object.` part, then the call will go on `self`.

If you do want to call a private method, you can always use `object.send(:func_pri)`.

Ruby is quite different than languages like Java in these terms. For more information, you might want to take a look at http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/, chapter 'Classes, Objects, and Variables', section 'Access Control'

Comment: Similar to `this` in java. When you din't specify a receiver for a method, it goes to self instead (ie self is the implicit receiver)